# Bates Model Jump Percentage Parameters

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-volatility, exotics, jump, bates

I am trying to calculate the jump parameters for the [Bates](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/aeb2/7f9b4bef0875d2d34b4b603651e4dcf6bbdf.pdf) volatility jumps, specifically, the mean of the jump percentages, $\mu_j$. For the value of $J$, I am using jumps $|\frac{s_{i}-s_{i-1}}{s_{i-1}}| > jump_{thresh}$ for a given $jump_{thresh}$ and stock prices $s_i \in [s_0, ..., s_n]$.

For the value of $\mu_j$, I am simply taking the mean of $\frac{s_{i}-s_{i-1}}{s_{i-1}}$. I am struggling to find solid documentation and research papers that provide in-depth information on this. Am I computing this correctly?

Comment: I read Bates Motel; and was scared off from approaching this one. Sorry :-) maybe reframing the question as Bates Motel Survival Probability will melt-up the participation? Gap-to-default risks need a sex life too, lest they never reproduce.